# Store data with loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need your help in this situation.
I want to store data that come from the form into the database in below table in one submit
[image: as you see in this picture meta_key define that what is meta_value.]

this is the form that I take data from it
[image]

I confused that how I can store rule in meta_key column when meta_value is some rules and store address in meta_key when meta_value is the address of someplace

Comment: This is a very unclear question. what are you entering in course_rules input?

Comment: something like: every student must be on time in their class.

Comment: Don't understand your queation. But if you want to pass multiple input in same name, then send it as array by `name="rules[]"`

Comment: I know this, no problem thanks for your answer. maybe someone knows what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

while storing your form data you can use the following code:

```
 if(isset($_POST['address']))
    {
          $meta_key="address";
          $meta_value=$_POST['address'];
          // Insert into Database
    }
    if(isset($_POST['rules']))
    {
          $meta_key="rule";
          $meta_value=$_POST['rules'];
          // Insert into Database
    }
```

If you are using loop as defined in your question then you should pass name parameters in form as:

```
 <input type="text" id="rules" name="rules[]" value="course_rule">
 <input type="text" id="address" name="address[]" value="address">
```